# Углы на блоке (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Добрых времени суток, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такие вот углы при наведении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.text{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: white;
}
.text::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px;
  top: -3px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.text::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
.text:hover::after, .text:hover::before{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="text">Some text</h1>
```

Comment: Большую часть в `.text::after` и `.text::before` можно объединить

Comment: @Spartacus интересно, поделитесь)

Comment: а чем тут делиться?) все просто `.text::after, .text::before {` и объединить схожие стили

Comment: @Spartacus имхо, в данном случае на производительность не влияет вообще никак, но спасибо за замечание)